# Displaying footer widgets data in front end using codeigniter framework

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have created backend functionality for adding footer data and displaying that footer data in front end. But while fetching the data  and displaying it is working only for `index.php` page but not for remaining pages. In the remaining pages getting php error as Message:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$get_in_touch.

I created a database and stored header images and footer data in a single table. So while fetching it is not working for other pages. Here is my code:

**Welcome (this is my index page controller):**

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('index_model');
    $data['records2'] = $this->index_model->get_all_client_images();
    $data['mainpage'] = "index";
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

**Testimonial Controller (where I am not able to display footer data getting php error.):**

```
public function index()
{

    $this->load->model('testimonial_model');
    $data['records2'] = $this->testimonial_model->get_all_testimonials();
    $data['mainpage'] = "testimonial";
    $this->load->view('templates/template',$data);
}
```

**Model (Index_model):**

```
function get_all_client_images()
{

    $this->db->select('B.*');
    $this->db->from('banner AS B');
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $q->result();
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**testimonial_model:**

```
function get_all_testimonials()
{

    $this->db->select('T.*');
    $this->db->from('testimonials AS T');
    $this->db->where(array('T.status'=>1));
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $q->result();
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**footer.php**

```
<?php if(isset($records2) && is_array($records2)):?>
            <?php foreach ($records2 as $r):?>
<div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-sm-3 ">
                        <div class="footerWidget ">
                            <h3 class="getintouch">Get In Touch</h3>
                            <address>
                                <p>
                                    <?php echo $r->get_in_touch;?>
                                    Phone: +91-080-420-131-80 <br>
                                    Cell:+91-924-128-9345<br>
                                    <a href="mailto:info@teknotrait.com" class="notification">Email: info@teknotrait.com</a>
                                </p>
                            </address>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 abouts">
                            <div class="footerWidget ">
                                <h3 class="ourcompany">Our Company</h3>
                                <?php echo $r->our_company;?>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 specializationss">
                            <div class="footerWidget ">
                                <h3 class="ourspecialization">Our Specialization</h3>
                                <?php echo $r->our_specialization;?>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: You don't show what is `$r`

Comment: @gdros updated the code what is $r

Comment: Well, it seems that your testimonial records don't have a `get_in_touch` field.

Comment: @gdros footer is common for all the pages so i nees to include that footer in testimonial page.

Comment: Yes, but you are trying to echo the `get_in_touch` property that doesn't exist in all cases. Put an `if(isset(...))` in front of it.

Comment: i am not getting you where i need to add if(isset()) condition

Comment: In your footer.php you echo the `$r->get_in_touch` parameter. This means that in every page that you include this footer, the `$r` object should contain a `get_in_touch` variable. If you can't satisfy the above constraint then you should check if the parameter exists before you try to echo it.

Answer (score 0):

**try**

```
 $this->db->where('status','1');
$q = $this->db->get('testimonials');
```

**instead of**

```
 $this->db->select('T.*');
$this->db->from('testimonials AS T');
$this->db->where(array('T.status'=>1));
$q = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: As i am getting testimonials but not able to display footer data which i am adding from front end

Comment: for footer i am getting errors not for testimonials

Comment: oh..!! ok.
Did u try to 'print_r($records2)' in your footer.php file to verify all contents are fetched or not ?

Comment: getting error as PHP has encountered an error.Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$get_in_touch.

Comment: try 
`  <?php if($records2 != ''){
             foreach ($records2 as $r) { ?>
<div class="col-md-12">
                  |
                  |
                  |
                  |
            </div>
                    <?php } } ?>`

Comment: if i mention get_in_touch in testimonial database it is working fine if not then it is not able to fetch the record.